# Which verb do I use to say I remove makeup and accessories, but in the same sentence as one another, when both of those have a separate verb for each?

Tags: verbs

I am a beginner in Japanese. Right now I am learning verbs and how to put together sentences, but I am stuck when it comes to which verb to use when there are so many subtleties for different things.  I want to write a sentence to say I take off both my makeup and accessories before bed. Is it 落とす or 外す? Or is it something else? I understood 落とす was for makeup, and 外す was for accessories. But what if I am removing both of those things in the same sentence? How do I know which verb to use when those two things usually require a separate verb?

Here is the sentence I am going to write:

> I take off my makeup and accessories before going to bed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would need to use both.

> 化粧を落として、アクセサリーを外してから寝る。

化粧を外す would sound like you peel off your makeup like a sheet mask or something, whereas アクセサリーを落とす would mean you either accidentally or intentionally drop them.

There is a way to unify them, though, as 取る happens to work well enough for both.

> 化粧とアクセサリーを取ってから寝る。

But this doesn’t work too well if you take off you shoes, too. You would need to use a separate verb.

> 靴を脱いで、化粧とアクセサリーを取ってから寝る。

You can also say メイク for makeup.